# flash symbol/movieclip animation loss on drag operation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

My scene has a tween animated symbol which is just some text. I added drag/drop functionality to the symbol via code snippets, which works finei.

However when a drag operation begins the animation of the symbol stops and never resumes.

Anyway at all to fix this?

If not then is it possible at all to have any sort of animated anything still animate while dragging? Ie. Animated GIF, sequence of images, .avi file etc etc

Comment: What are using to animate? code tween or a timeline frame-to-frame tween?   What exactly do you want animated?

Comment: Most likely what you'll want is to encapsulate your text (the thing you want to drag) into a parent movie clip.  Have the drag happen on the parent and tweens happen on stuff inside it.

Comment: Also, are you trying to drag the same object that is being tweened/animated?

Comment: it is a tween I created on the timeline not in code.. it's a motion tween.. in my current scene what needs to be animated is what also needs to be dragged which is also just plane ol normal text/classic text with some filters that change as part of the animation..the animation on the filters is on the symbol...

Comment: So London I need a symbol/movie clip inside a symbol/movie clip?

Comment: Clip1.clip2.mytext, clip1 received drag/drop. clip2 received tween / animation?